# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs

I'm facing this problem that I couldn't figure out
the description of the problem seems that is cuss problem, but I used pure simple CSS
I am disappointed that I was thinking to drop the react js learning
[image: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

this is my components

```
import React from "react";

const ProductForm = ({ setNewProduct, handleAddProductSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form className="form-add-new" onSubmit={handleAddProductSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="[name] [forme] [dosage] [packing]"
        name="name"
        className="form-control w-50"
        onChange={(e) => setNewProduct({ name: e.target.value })}
      />
      <button className="btn btn-primary mx-3">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProductForm;
```

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ProductForm from "./ProductForm";
import authContext from "../../Context/AuthContext";
import axios from "axios";
import useAxios from "../../utils/useAxios";

const OrdersForm = ({ handlesubmit }) => {
  const { baseURL } = useContext(authContext);

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState();
  const [addProduct, setAddProduct] = useState({ product: "", qtt: "" });
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({ name: "" });
  const api = useAxios();
  function handlechangeorders(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setAddProduct((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  }
  const handleAddProductSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    api
      .post(`${baseURL}api/orders/add-product/`, newProduct)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setProductsList((prev) => {
          return [...prev, addProduct];
        });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${baseURL}api/orders/products/`).then((response) => {
      setProductsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="orders-form cmd-form-container">
      <form className="form-add-list" onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="product"
          name="product"
          placeholder="Choose your product"
          className="form-control"
          list="products-list"
          onChange={handlechangeorders}
          required
        />
        <datalist id="products-list">
          {productsList?.map((product) => {
            return <option key={product.id} value={product.name} />;
          })}
        </datalist>
        <div className="new" onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>
          New
        </div>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="qtt"
          name="qtt"
          placeholder="QTT"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={handlechangeorders}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </form>
      {visible && (
        <ProductForm
          setNewProduct={setNewProduct}
          handleAddProductSubmit={handleAddProductSubmit}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default OrdersForm;
```

the axios in useEffect is retrieving more than 7000 objects (thinking may be the large retrieved data is the problem)
if this is not enough I can add some other details

I have days trying to solve this any helps would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Looks like a recurrence caused by a state triggering the change of another state. `State 1` change -> `State 2` change -> `State 1`..... Try to implement without the setNewProduct and setAddProduct states.

Comment: If I remove those states the code wouldn't work or you mean something else?